# Is there any standard way to use boolean? because my code is giving an error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
boolean ch(char x)
{

if(x>=48&&x<=57)
return 1;
else
return 0;

}
main()
{

if(!ch('t'))
printf("it's a character");

}
```

error:

cha.c:3: error: `boolean' does not name a type
cha.c: In function`int main()':
cha.c:15: error: `ch' was not declared in this scope

Comment: For more consistency and readability, you should use '0' and '9' instead of 48 and 57.

Comment: yes i was using that then just for checking the(ASCII) values i entered these values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the C99 standard has introduced the `_Bool` type

#### Update

Apparently `<stdbool.h>` also includes the prettier `bool` type in addition to the `true` and `false` macros.  Updated code to reflect this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ch(int);

int main(void)
{
    if(!ch('t'))
        printf("it's a character\n");
    return 0;
}

bool ch(int x)
{
    if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Click [**this link**](http://ideone.com/DHQrp) to see the compiled code's output

Comment: @Charlie Nothing he said would lead me to that conclusion. Also, if he is not, perhaps he will now that he knows it standardizes the bool type

Comment: I'd just like to add that `_Bool` is available without "stdbool.h".

Comment: What @Jens said.  <stdbool.h> provides the prettier "bool" typedef.

Comment: Indeed. If you're going to include `stdbool.h`, don't use the ugly `_Bool` name, use `bool`. But better yet, just use `int` like everyone else...

Comment: _Bool is intrinsically available (in C99) and does not need the `<stdbool.h>` header.  The header makes macros `bool`, `true` and `false` available (and defines `_ _bool_true_false_are_defined` too).  Unusually, you are allowed to redefine the three macros in the user namespace.

Comment: @Jens as Jonathan mentioned I included `stdbool.h` for the `true` and `false` macros.  However, I wasn't aware that it also included the prettier `bool`.  Updated code to reflect that. Thanks

Comment: R.. is right, if you attempt to integrate stdbool.h code with C++ for instance there are difficulties in the width of C's bool vs. C++'s bool. _Bool is probably the right way to handle this. int is better.

Answer (score 1):

And googling wins again

[Boolean Expressions and Variables : What is the right type to use for Boolean values in C? Is there a standard type? Should I use #defines or enums for the true and false values?](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=bool)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm crazy, C doesn't have a `boolean` type. Change the return type of `ch` to `int`

Also, post your error message.

Comment: so we cant get boolean type results like true or false in c??

Comment: No. C does not have `boolean` types. Using 0 and 1 is the 'standard' way of doing it.

Comment: so how should i write to get a result in true or false format?

Comment: Why do you need true or false format? What exactly is 'true or false format'? What's wrong with 0 for false 1 for true?

Comment: that means is should use int type??

Comment: Yeah, use an int. The only use case I see for specifically needing bool type is that if you don't want to use the 4 bytes it takes to store an int whereas a bool can be 1 byte.

Comment: You're crazy, I guess, because C certainly does have the _Bool type.

Comment: Firstly,`_Bool` isn't `boolean` and his question was basically 'why doesn't my code compile'. Second, I guess it depends what version of C we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have a built-in `boolean` type. A `bool` type is available in the `stdbool.h` header in the standard library in C99.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h

Comment: C99 *has* a boolean type, even without the header, namely `_Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got more problems than just the type, however.  `if(x>=48&&x<=57)` doesn't mean what you think it does, and your printf is going to give you unexpected results too.

You're going to need these characters: "(())\n" and a bunch of whitespace.

Sorry to be a little cryptic but this looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement `if (boolean_expression) return true; else return false;` can always be replaced by `return boolean_expression;` which I find a lot more readable.

Also, your naming is terrible, what does `ch` stand for? Since 48 is `0` and 47 is `9`, a better name would probably be `is_digit` or something. (And, as others have noted, C89 does not have a boolean type.)

```
int is_digit(char c)
{
    return (c >= '0') && (c <= '9');
}
```

The parenthesis are optional, but I think they make the code more readable.

And what do you mean by the output "It's a character" in main? Every `char` is a character, duh :)